# APK Expansions android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk-expansion-files

I need to separate my drawable images in expansion file because if I didn't separate them when I make an update to my app the user will download all the app again which 54 Mbytes, but if I separate them the user will download the apk only which is 5 Mbytes.

I try to follow the instruction of android developer documentation 
https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files#AboutLibraries

they are saying here how to add this library

Preparing to use the Downloader Library
To use the Downloader Library, you need to download two packages from the SDK Manager and add the appropriate libraries to your application.

First, open the Android SDK Manager (Tools > SDK Manager), and under Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK, select the SDK Tools tab to select and download:

Google Play Licensing Library package
Google Play APK Expansion Library package
Create a new library module for the License Verification Library and Downloader Library. For each library:

1. Select File > New > New Module.
2. In the Create New Module window, select Android Library, and then select Next.
3. Specify an Application/Library name such as "Google Play License Library" and "Google Play Downloader Library", choose Minimum SDK level, then select 
   Finish.

   4. Select File > Project Structure.
   5. Select the Properties tab and in Library Repository, enter the library from 
      the /extras/google/ directory (play_licensing/ for the License 
      Verification Library or play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the 
      Downloader Library).
   6. Select OK to create the new module.

I tried to do the above steps but no thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to minimize the image size by adding the screenshots of those draw able images.I know this is not the perfect way to minimize the size ,but I also faced this problem and I did the same.

Comment: whatever the size I will minimize to still the same problem happens which is the user will redownload the app again when any updates happen.
so I need to put the images in expansion file.
Can you help me with that?